# How can I use the Collision Deformer in MegaFiers?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, collision, mesh

I'm new to Unity & MegaFiers.  I've tried to find a tutorial on how to use the collision deformer everywhere but I can't find anything.  I have a mesh renderer on a skinned mesh and I'm trying to deform it when it pusses up against other objects.  The collision deformer sounds perfect for this, but I just can't get it working!

Do you know how to use the collision deformer or are you aware of a tutorial anywhere that will show me how to use it?

Thanks

Comment: Is this collision deformer coming from Megafiers?  Unity doesn't natively support mesh deformation that I am aware of.  Your best bet is to roll your own, maybe do something like [free form deformation](http://www.seethroughskin.com/blog/?p=619)?  I'm not sure of Stackoverflow's policy on self promotion so in the interest of full disclosure I will point out that the link is to my site.

Comment: @Jerdak - Interesting site.  I don't think that I'll be able to optimize the code as well as the megafiers' guys have.  And yes, megafiers offer a collision deformer that works REALLY well (or so I've been told 26ms - peak time for a very complex deformation).  So I'd rather use their stuff since I've already paid for it!

Comment: Now that I've had more of a chance to look at their engine I see that it's not just a static manipulator that applies these effects pre-processed.  And yeah, my implementation is slow as crap, I threw it out there in case what you were using didn't actually offer a real time solution.  Good luck with your version, I think at $150 it'll be hard to find users who have tried it out.

Comment: @Jerdak - There seem to be a lot of people using it, but no one seems to have used this specific part of it for some reason.  Your solution is good and not too slow, but on a mobile device I need to squeeze all the savings I can out of the app!

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the system the collision deformer is is still in early alpha, it was added so a user could play with the code. I will be finishing the deformer of soon and adding proper docs and tutorials for it.